# Is it possible to add an extra value (a calculation of 2 fields in the query) to a queryset that is returned from class based view

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a value to a query that is returned from a class based view. My Db consists of users, a user can have many transactions, and a transaction can have many sales. I want to calculate the profit loss on a sale by means of `((sale.amount_per_coin - sale.transaction.amount_per_coin_sold) * sale.amount)` and add it to each row that is returned. Is it possible to do this and if so how would I go about doing it.

Transaction Model Below

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_per_coin = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin = self.total_price / self.amount
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Sale Model Below

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    amount_sold = models.IntegerField()
    total_price_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    date_sold = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_per_coin_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin_sold = self.total_price_sold / self.amount_sold
        super(Sale, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

class based view below

```
class SaleListView(ListView):
    model = Sale
    template_name = 'webapp/sale.html'
    context_object_name = 'sales'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(transaction__owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: You can define a function in the model class to compute this 'profit-loss', add a property referencing this function, and then this property will be included in the queryset output like any other (database) field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by ***adding the value to the queryset*** you mean that the value should be available on the items of the queryset you could make a property on `Sale` that performs that calculation as such:

```
@property
def profit_loss(self):
    return (self.amount_per_coin - self.transaction.amount_per_coin_sold) * self.amount
```

which you can later use it in your template as `{{ sale.profit_loss }}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible just use an annotation (see [Aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#)):

```
sales = Sales.objects.filter(
    transaction=transaction      # Filter on the desire transaction.
).annotate(
    profit_lost=(F('amount_per_coin') - F('transaction__amount_per_coin_sold')) * F('amount')
)
```

now you will have the attribute `proft_lost` for every `sale` in the `sales` queryset.